# Asp.net core Type must not be ByRef Parameter name: type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

when i run this method it shows below error,

```
public bool SaveDocument(out string newDocumentNo, ReciptUpdate reciptUpdate)
{
    newDocumentNo = "MB120055";
    return true;            
}
```

The error is

> ArgumentException: Type must not be ByRef
>    Parameter name: type

Comment: Which line is throwing that exception?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: How you can set out param in action method?

Comment: when i set the break point that method.but without executing the method that error occurs

Comment: I normally set the out parameter in action method

Comment: Interesting, but not much to go on.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error message because I added an "in" modifier to a controller method when tinkering with some optimisation and didn't notice that it broke the aspnet.core runtime invocation of the method (resulting in this somewhat cryptic error)

The original method signature:

```
public IActionResult ReceiveMessage(string topicName, [FromBody] in CloudEvent update)
```

The fix:

```
public IActionResult ReceiveMessage(string topicName, [FromBody] CloudEvent update)
```

Answer (score 0):

a sample code for your method. When use your method for you must put out method in first parameter.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string docNo = string.Empty;
  SaveDocument(out docNo, new ReciptUpdate() { });
}

 public static bool SaveDocument(out string newDocumentNo, ReciptUpdate reciptUpdate)
{
   newDocumentNo = "MB120055";
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had `in` modifiers on the destination mappings when using Automapper.